How can I suppress, disable the message "are you sure you want to copy this folder without properties" and related check
I understand the NTFS to FAT32 format problem but THAT is not my problem. I am coping from a NVME M.2 NTFS partition to a EXFAT SD Card.
I do not care about file properties.
How can I skip this step / annoying message permanently?
Where is this message in windows 10?  I will rip it out with my bare hands.

While I understand you are frustrated, your understanding this should make you understand it IS your problem, and the OS will only do what you tell it. You would hate the OS more if it assumed things about what you wanted. There are already well known and documented tools for copying files that allow you to pre-answer for larger transfers. So, what research have you done and what have you tried? Please note that this is a professional site, and the best-received questions, answers, and other interactions will remain professional.
